# What will HAWQ Resource Manager do if YARN behaves unnormal when running some queries?

Tags: resourcemanager, hawq

For example, if YARN was stopped by some unknown reasons when running query1. At this time, query2 allocates resources to run. YARN restarts after a few minutes.  Will query1 and query2 both run normally?

Answer (score 0):

Once the query succeeds in obtaining the resource(called vseg in HAWQ), the query will run no matter the status of YARN is down.

Comment: As you said, query2 will keep waiting for resource until YARN restarts?

Answer (score 0):

HAWQ Resource Manager will periodically contact Yarn.

If the down of Yarn has not been found by HAWQ Resource Manager, and HAWQ Resource Manager still contains the resources, both query1 and query2 can run successfully. But if the down of Yarn is found by HAWQ Resource Manager, following queries will all hang until Yarn becomes back.